# If I decline to join a Master's program, can the university deny admission to me if I apply on the next year?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, university

Suppose I get selected for an American/Canadian University for a masters in computer science as an international student for fall 2022 , but I decline to join the university due to some personal reasons. Will the university save my application details?

Could they deny me admission if I re-apply to the same university in the next year?

Furthermore, does any university provide a provision where I can defer the admission to the next year?

Comment: You are better off accepting to join, and immediately asking to pause your studies.
Get in touch with the enrollment office: you can be transparent with them, plus each university may have different rules

Comment: Deferring admission is not uncommon (and often used during Covid). Whether they will or not is up to them. Unlikely the university wants to save applications - that is a headache of personal information to protect. If you reapply, it is a new applicant pool and there is no way to know how you would stack up against the new pool.

Comment: Is it possible for a university to reject my application on the next year just because i had declined to join in the previous year?

Answer (score 3):

The comments give good advice (EarlGrey and Jon Custer), but to answer the question, I think it would be unusual to turn you down for that reason alone. If you have already told them no, then you can try again in a year. But, in a competitive program the outcome might not be the same next time, so if you haven't yet acted, try to accept with a deferral.

In an interview, you might be asked for reasons. Be prepared with an honest, but convincing reason.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

Declining is not the same as deferring. If you defer, then you are effectively still admitted, you just do not attend that year. If you decline, then you are saying you will not attend. The university will call up students on their wait list, and forget about you. If you change your mind you'll have to submit a new application next year, and deal with the changing circumstances - e.g. your (new) competitors, the funding situation, COVID, etc. There is no guarantee you'll be accepted in the new round, although it's not impossible either.

As for

> Furthermore, does any university provide a provision where I can defer the admission to the next year?

You'd have to ask the university. There's a good chance the answer is yes, but you still need to ask.